# How long an innings can be played with one ball?

Tags: rules, cricket

In test match format new ball can be taken after 80 overs. My question is that if bowling side captain don't want to take new ball after 80 overs then how much can he use old ball

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He can continue to use the old ball until either he chooses to take the new ball, or until it's declared unfit and is changed by the umpires. However, it's supposed to be changed for one of similar age, so that will complicate things. See [Law 5](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-5-the-ball/).

In practice a captain will use an old ball if it's working for the spinners, but eventually it will go out of shape, and it will be worth it to take the new ball, if only to give the spinners a rest.

Comment: Note that a captain may also choose to keep bowling with an old ball if his/her bowlers are obtaining _reverse swing_ with it.

Comment: He can continue with it no matter what it's doing, the type of bowling is irrelevant.

Comment: I'm aware of that. I was merely highlighting an additional factor (reverse swing) that may incline a captain to persist with an old ball.

Answer (score 1):

The captain can use the ball for as long as he wishes, so long as the ball is fit for play. If the ball is unfit for play,

> the umpires shall replace it with a ball which has had wear comparable with that which the previous ball had received before the need for its replacement

([Law 5.5](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-5-the-ball/)). However, the [Standard Test Match Playing Conditions](http://icc-live.s3.amazonaws.com/cms/media/about_docs/559921c7a5bb8-1%20_Standard_Test_July_2015.pdf) include the provision that

> if the ball needs to be replaced after 110 overs for any of the reasons above, it shall be replaced by a new ball.

This provision was brought in after a couple of incidents where captains were continuing to bowl with very old balls, and it was becoming increasingly hard to find a ball with "comparable wear".